# in other element, not working phonegap event api ex) backbutton

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

it's working
but

```
var element = $("#score-screen")[0];
element.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    element.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

score-screen is div id
it's not working..
help me.. please

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that device ready and BackButton be fired only on the document.

Phonegap documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should
>   use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However,
>   JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web
>   application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function
>   before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded.
>   After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova
>   function.
>
> Typically, you will want to attach an event listener with
>   document.addEventListener once the HTML document's DOM has loaded.
>
> This event behaves differently from others in that any event handler
>   registered after the event has been fired will have its callback
>   function called immediately.